# Change show/hide button location in ui-grid angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Is there a good and fast way to move the show/hide column button to another location without implement new function for this operation?

I tried to use broadcast/watch, but this not working.

Comment: What do you mean with 'another location'? Position in the dropdown? Or the position of the dropdown trigger button? Or somwhere outside the grid? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi. I meant the position of the dropdown trigger button, I want to locate it above the grid. Thanks

Comment: You mean above each respective column?

Comment: No, I want to create new button that will be located in another location on my page, this button will manage show/hide columns

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. You want a (single) button that, when it's clicked, hides a certain column or a set of columns? That is a completely different thing than mowing the column menu to a new location. And for sure you need a small script/function to do that.

Comment: Hi, ui-grid(ng-grid) have a button in the side that if you click it, it opens a menu with all your columns name, if you click on column name it hides the column. this button is located in the grid header. I want to change the location of this button. like in this example : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/304_grid_menu

Comment: Uh, we are talking about the grid menu not the individuaal column menus here. Sorry, I have a terrible cold and I'm a bit slow today. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you, this is the most easiest answer.

Add this to your last loaded CSS:

```
.ui-grid-menu-button {
    position: relative;
}
```

This will position a large button above the grid.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gG6a629wKFmn61WACaSZ?p=preview)

But somehow I think that is still not what you wanted.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking, I want to create my own button, different from the default one, that will be located in different position and will open the menu from your example, I need the menu also to open under my new button.

Comment: this will work 
.ui-grid-menu-button .ui-grid-menu{
    left: 0 !important;
    right: auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using css itself,

Below CSS will postion both grid menu button and grid menu item in same position

```
 .ui-grid-menu-button {
    position: relative !important;
    right: auto !important;
  }

.ui-grid-menu-button .ui-grid-menu{
    left: 0 !important;
 }
```